# Dispatching a runtime call from an ink! smart contract

Tags: ink, runtime, pallet-contracts

*Disc: I know about the existence of `ChainExtension` feature. Here I would like to ask about the other way.*

There is this `CallFilter` thing in `Config` for `pallet-contracts` and IIUC it defines what kind of runtime calls I can do from within the contract. In all examples I saw, it is set to `Nothing`. Let's suppose I set it to `Everything` - what kind of runtime calls I can then do from a contract? Where can I find an example how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will allow a contract to call every dispatchable of every pallet just as any off chain actor could do by submitting an extrinsic. See the [documentation of `seal_call_runtime`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/e0ccd008fe8bfaf29357ea87561e60f3baaae08c/frame/contracts/src/wasm/runtime.rs#L1924-L1960) for more information.

Please note that this functionality is currently flagged [unstable](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/contracts#unstable-interfaces) and therefore not to be used in production, yet. It is unclear whether the functionality is actually useful it its current form. There is also no support within ink!, yet. Hence I don't know of any example.